# Parse URL parameter via JS but add just the first eight characters as value into a HTML form

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, input, parameters

I try to pass a parameter via URL to a HTML form using some Java Script.
For example this URL:

```
http://www.sample.com/?12345
```

passes the value "12345" to this input:

```
<input type="text" id="CodeAdd">
```

via this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("CodeAdd").value = location.search.replace('?','');
};
```

Everything works fine. After opening the page via the above URL+parameter the script prefills the input field with "12345".

But everyone can prefill anything into it. Including, for example, 4000 characters of JavaScript. Seems very unsecured to me...

So I just want to parse out the first, let me say, 8 characters so that this URL

```
http://www.sample.com/?12345678910111213
```

will return just

```
12345678
```

instead of:

```
12345678910111213
```

Whats the best way to archive it/proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `string.substr(/*start pos*/, /*no of char*/)` to solve both problems:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("CodeAdd").value = location.search.substr(1, 8);
};
```

`http://www.sample.com/?12345678910111213` will return just `12345678`

That being said, you could also:

- make the input hidden (so the user doesn't see it and can't edit it)

  ```
  <input id="CodeAdd" type="hidden">
  ```
- disable the input (so the user sees it but can't edit it)

  ```
  <input id="CodeAdd" type="text" disabled="disabled">
  ```

Also note that you should *still* validate the input at the server-side, as anyone can post anything they want regardless of your script.

Comment: Perfect! Solved the issue!